# Kendo Timeline View example different names

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

in this kendo example "http://dojo.telerik.com/iGemI" is there any way to assign different people for different "Meeting Rooms" instead of having the same persons for the different "Meeting Rooms".

Output like this
[image]

Comment: Please look into resources property, you need to add new record for attendees data source..

Comment: I could not find anywhere a solution to my problem

Comment: Luis Tiago, did u able to achieve this customization?

Comment: Dion Dirza, Can you add a dojo ?

Comment: Dion Dirza, adding new record for attendees will make it visible in all the groups, requirement is to have different people for different group